# Custom Partitioner for skewed data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a whole world data of some usecase. Each country contains 3 to 5 products, which is collected every hour for each user. I want to do bootstrapping to calculate some average and other ratios per country per product per hour.

```
input.rdd.map(
      row => (
        (country, product, hour),
        (country, product, hour, user, rating)
        )
    )
val groups = keyGroup.groupByKey()
val output = groups.flatMapValues(x => bootstrap(x)).toDF
```

The problem is some countries data is quite big, which is causing the whole process to take hours and still not finish. I try to get the size which is roughly:

```
Partition:count ->Countries

0: 2044816 -> India,Turkey

1: 1466790 -> Turkey,India

2: 783772 -> India,Mexico,Japan,South Korea

3: 431538 -> Japan,Mexico,South Korea,India,Indonesia,Turkey,Brazil,Russian Federation

4: 319824 -> South Korea,Brazil,Russian Federation,India,Mexico,United States of America,Turkey,Japan,Bangladesh

5: 268698 -> Bangladesh,Nigeria,Russian Federation,United States of America

6: 264709 -> Russian Federation,United States of America,Germany,Bangladesh,Nigeria,South Africa

7: 227612 -> South Africa,United States of America,Russian Federation,Brazil,South Korea,Germany
...
...
167: 58 -> Mexico,Chile,Uganda,Thailand,Ivory Coast,Antigua and Barbuda,Palau,Luxembourg,United States of America,British Virgin Islands,Iceland,Andorra,Samoa,Vanuatu,Botswana,Saint Lucia,Kiribati,Greenland

168: 69 -> Greenland,Iceland,Chile,Zambia,Estonia,Vanuatu,Cyprus,Malta,Saudi Arabia,Japan,Uruguay,Qatar,United States of America,Luxembourg,Peru,Belize,Papua New Guinea,Samoa,South Sudan

169: 61 -> Myanmar,Belize,Chile,Somalia,Bhutan,Luxembourg,Liberia,Norway,United Kingdom,Burkina Faso,Lithuania,Macedonia,Belgium,Vanuatu,Burundi,DR Congo,Montenegro,Central African Republic,Bosnia and Herzegovina

170: 36 -> Mauritania,Sierra Leone,Hungary,Zambia,Somalia,Federated States of Micronesia,Serbia,Liberia,Nepal,Chile,Israel,Ukraine,Montenegro,Yemen,Croatia,Central African Republic,Armenia,Andorra,United Arab Emirates,Mauritius,Albania,Lebanon,Macedonia

171: 25 -> Spain,Comoros,Libya,Peru,Latvia,Montenegro,Egypt,Malaysia,Central African Republic,Faroe Islands,Tanzania,Palau,Chad,Guatemala,Kiribati,Burundi,Luxembourg,Equatorial Guinea,Barbados,Belgium

172: 14 -> Vietnam,Tanzania,Hungary,Egypt,Comoros,Equatorial Guinea,Guinea-Bissau,Moldova,Macedonia,Guyana,Federated States of Micronesia,New Zealand,Chad
```

It can be seen that the data is not divided evenly, and it has **173** partitions. The data is around 6 GB which contains a week data. If I try to run single single country by doing **repartition of 1000** it works, but together it doesn't work.

I am thinking to write a **custom partitioner** but I have no clue how should I break that data for bigger countries count. It would be great if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Before you go down the path of writing your own custom partitioner you can try this:
Since you already know which countries have skewed data you can create a composite key with randomly appended numbers in some range (wider range for more skewed data) for said countries. You can aggregate on said key and later drop the composite key and aggregate further.

```
df.withColumn("composite_key", 
    when(isSkewDataCountryUDF(col("country")), concat(col("country"), randomNumberSuffix())
    .otherwise(col("country")))
.groupBy("composite_key")
.count
.drop("composite_key")
.groupBy("country")
.count
```

Also try to set a much higher `spark.default.parallelism` and `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`